# Reading data from a plist file

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to implement a Save State for my iPhone App.

I've got a plist file called SaveData.plist and I can read it in via the following

```
NSString *pListPath2 = [bundle pathForResource:@"SaveData" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary2 = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListPath2];

self.SaveData = dictionary2;
[dictionary release];
```

The Plist file has members

SavedGame which is a Boolean to tell the app if there really is valid data here (if they did not exit the app in the middle of a game, I don't want their to be a Restore Point.

Score which is an NSNumber.
Time which is an NSNumber

Playfield which is a 16 element array of NSNumbers

How do I access those elements inside of the NSDictionary?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try `[NSDictionary objectForKey:]`

Where Key is the name of the member in the plist.

For example:

```
BOOL save = [[dictionary2 objectForKey:@"SavedGame"] boolValue];
```

will store the object stored in the plist for the key SavedGame into a new BOOL named save.

I imagine that your SavedGame Boolean is actually stored in the `NSDictionary` as an `NSNumber`, hence the use of boolValue to get the Boolean Value of the `NSNumber`.

Try this documentation:  [Apple NSDictionary Reference](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-BBCIBCDJ).

Comment: Always use -objectForKey: if you're calling directly — if you read the docs, -valueForKey: is used for key-value observing and Cocoa Bindings. It won't return the wrong result, but it does unnecessary work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

For Setting Bool Value You can Use :

`[Dictionary setBool:TRUE forKey:@"preference"];`

For Getting Bool value you can use :

`[Dictionary boolForKey:@"preference"];`