# Search on Arrays inside Plist in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, arrays, search, plist

I'm developing an app that should search a string inside the Plist data and return a value that should prompt the user what kind of, say brand it is. For example, the user inputs "iPhone" in my text field and the app should return the brand of the product the user inputted after tapping the Go button below the text field.

Inside my Products.plist, It contains arrays of brands with certain products that brand has. Example would be:

Apple: iPhone, iPod, iPad, Mac
Sony: PSP, PS3, Bravia, Xperia
Samsung: Galaxy S II, Galaxy S III, Galaxy Tab

How can I do this? I have already done my app working fine but without using a plist. I just want to use a Plist for the app to be easily maintained and updated.

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067167/reading-data-from-a-plist-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your plist file is called data.plist, this is how you should do this:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];    
NSString *pListpath = [bundle pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pListpath];

for (NSString* key in [dictionary allKeys]){
    NSArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    for (int j = 0; j < [array count]; j++) {
        if ([[array objectAtIndex:j] isEqualToString:@"iPhone"]) {
            NSLog(@"%@",key);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this case, for iPhone, the response logged is Apple.

Comment: Thanks for this Bijoy Thangaraj. Will try it out and accept your answer if it works. :)

Comment: Where can I place my error log in the code? Can you guide me where? Thanks

Comment: @jaytrixz In Xcode, you can go to View->Debug Area->Activate Console to see the output window where the errors are logged.

Comment: Nope, I meant where can I place my code where after going thru the for loops, it'll prompt the user that the app didn't find anything on the list.

Comment: @jaytrixz I am unclear with your question. Maybe, you can ask it in a separate thread.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it all working now. Apologies for the confusion.